# Feature request: New users get notified to visit questions frequently after asking first question

Tags: feature-request, new-users

My idea is targeted towards new users. Many of these users join SO to ask a question. They ask it, and after not getting a reply in the first few minutes, vanish. This is an issue, especially for those who devoted their time an effort into answering the question.

When a new user, say less than a few days old, asks their first question, they are told that:

1. They may not receive an answer in the first few minutes
2. They should edit the question as necessary to provide information
3. They should check the question when they can. Just because a question doesn’t get an answer right away does **not** mean that they won’t get one at all.
4. If and when they do get an answer that works, they should show respect and appreciation to the answerer by accepting the answer, and, if they feel that the answer is worthy, vote up on the question.

I feel that many new users don’t understand these things about the site and quickly leave because of it. They expect an answer right away, and are dissatisfied when they don’t get that.

I think this would help answers be properly recognized. Many of my answers are correct but not accepted because the asker disappeared. By letting the asker know that answers don’t come immediately, it benefits both the asker and the answerer.

I think this is an idea that could substantially help new users stay longer and help answerer receive credit for their answers.

Comment: If users cannot understand that the world spins once in 24 hrs, and that other users have lives, need to sleep, eat, work etc, they don't really deserve any free help:(

Comment: The notification needs to be actionable and the criteria for when the notification is send need to be fleshed out a bit. On the actionable part, I would prefer if they get linked to the help center or so, if possible with exact guidance matching the state of the question. For example: if the question got low views, suggest to edit and check if the correct tags are present. When it got a down vote provide indo on what a high-quality edit would look like, if it got a close vote ... if it got requires editing in triage ... etc. You get the idea.

Comment: It's not just new users. Slightly different from what you're addressing, but a surprising number of users with decent rep post questions but don't stick around, resulting in most of those who have been asking and hoping for clarification giving up and navigating away. A question which gets sufficiently clarified to be answerable in its first 5 minutes is far more likely to get helpful answers than one which gets clarified an hour later.

Comment: That’s definitely true

Answer (score 6):

I'm not convinced that people need to be reminded of they own questions.

In particular I'm very concerned to notify people who ask homework questions... Reminding "hey visit that question" when assignment is past due not going to lead to positive results... especially if all activity on the post is "please clarify X" comments. Even answer probably will get downvote (if OP can) as not-longer-useful and comment like "you @#$@# must answer faster to get points - I failed my course because your site @#$#".

Answer (score 4):

Why not displaying actual data to convey the messages you want to convey? We know quite well how long people wait on average for their answers.

- A histogram of the time until the first answer arrives could be displayed with some explanatory text. This should be dependent on the tags of the questions. As far as I can remember for less active tags, a first answer will likely come within a few days but not more. Just tell them the median waiting time for the first answer (if there is an answer) and also the chance to get at least one answer (on average for these tags).
- The motivation to edit might also be increased by showing a histogram of how much higher the score is, if the asker does at least a single edit.
- How frequently should they check? Maybe a better guidance can be given, because if we tell them to check every minute, they might lose interest quickly. Tell them the average frequency of comments ("questions with similar tags get X comments in the first hour, Y comments on the first day, so don't forget to check back regularly").
- Reminding people to accept questions is a big thing to learn for beginners. The UI could surely send a message after the first answer to a question came (for the first X questions) explaining the feature and why it's important and maybe a reminder after a certain time if no answer has been accepted. Of course it should also mention that only fully acceptable answers should be accepted. As far as I know such things are not done currently.

Comment: Could even be tag-based, as I'm sure a PHP tagged question will be more likely to get a quick answer vs. a less popular language

Comment: All great ideas

Answer (score 2):

I think a "someone answered your question" or maybe even "someone commented on your question" notification would be more useful than just a reminder to check back.  New users could be very discouraged to check back and find that no one had actually engaged with their question.  A notification that they got an answer, and should accept it if it is correct could improve site engagement because it is rewarding for the new user ("Oh hey, someone responded to me!") and to the answerer, as they don't have a correct answer that never gets accepted or even seen by the OP, which is a known 'risk' to answering a question posed by a new user.

Even if I have an older question, answered or unanswered, I would possibly be interested to see any additional answer that was added, as presumably the answerer thought they had a better, more complete, or more up to date answer.  Ideally this would be a 'daily digest' format for those who have many questions, so they don't get overwhelmed with emails.

Comment: There are comment and answer notifications though.